# Java bicycle and bicycle test

Tags: java

I have a problem to write my code. This is a code where I have to create an object class and run it using another class object.
The program is called bicycle and bicycletest.
I was given the bicycle program (its already been written) and all I need I write bicycletest to utilize the bicycle.
Now, the problem is, i have created 2 object, called NiceBicycle and CoolBicycle. I need to change my NiceBicycle name to "Kenny McCormick, but i cant do it. i keep getting error saying 
"error: variable NiceBicycle might not have been initialized" for this line of command that i write.

// Change the owner's name to Kenny McCormick using setOwnerName
    `NiceBicycle.setOwnerName("Kenny McCormick");`

what should i do?

anyway, here is the bicycle code, and bicycletest that i write based on the instructor command.
Thank you for your reply

bicycle.java

```
public class Bicycle
{

// Instance field
private String ownerName;
private int licenseNumber;

// Constructor
public Bicycle( String name, int license )
{
     ownerName = name;
     licenseNumber = license;
}

// Returns the name of this bicycle's owner
public String getOwnerName()
{
     return ownerName;
}

// Assigns the name of this bicycle's owner
public void setOwnerName( String name )
{
     ownerName = name;
}

// Returns the license number of this bicycle
public int getLicenseNumber()
{
     return licenseNumber;
}

// Assigns the license number of this bicycle
public void setLicenseNumber( int license ) 
{
     licenseNumber = license;
}
```

}

and here is bicycletest.java that i wrote.

```
  public class BicycleTest 
   {

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

    // Create 1 Bicycle reference variable. For example: myBike
    Bicycle NiceBicycle;

    // Create 1 String reference variable for the owner's name
    String name;

    // Create 1 integer variable for license number
    int licenceNumber;

    // Assign your full name and a license number to the String and
    // integer variables
    name = "Boo Yeah";
    int licenseNumber = 9972;

    // Create a Bicycle object with the Bicycle class constructor
    // Use the variables you created as arguments to the constructor
    Bicycle CoolBicycle = new Bicycle( "Boo Yeah", 9972 );

    // Output the owner's name and license number in printf statements
    // using the object reference and the get methods.
    // For example: bike.getOwnerName()
    System.out.printf ("The CoolBicycle owner's name is %s\nThe license number is %d\n", CoolBicycle.getOwnerName(), CoolBicycle.getLicenseNumber());

    // Change the owner's name to Kenny McCormick using setOwnerName
    NiceBicycle.setOwnerName("Kenny McCormick");

    // Output the owner's name and license number in printf statements
      // using the Bicycle object reference variable and the get methods.
      System.out.printf ("The NiceBicycle owner's name is %s\n", NiceBicycle.getOwnerName());
 }
```

}

Comment: Hi everyone. Thank you all for your input, I really appreciate it. The program works after I follow everyone's advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate Bicycle and assign it to NiceBicycle in your test by changing:

```
Bicycle NiceBicycle;
```

to:

```
Bicycle NiceBicycle = new Bicycle("", 0);
```

Then you can setOwnerName() on it:

```
NiceBicycle.setOwnerName("Kenny McCormick");
```

Also, note that Java conventions suggest that variable names start with lowercase letters, so **NiceBicycle** should really be **niceBicycle** if you want to follow Java conventions.

Answer (score 0):

NiceBicycle hasn't been initialised (the bicycle object hasn't been created).

Try replacing

```
Bicycle NiceBicycle;
```

With

```
Bicycle NiceBicycle = new Bicycle("",0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is being kind. You didn't set `NiceBicycle` before trying to use it. The variable is not set.

Also note that the Java convention is to always name variables starting with lower case, and classes starting with upper case.  This is important because `.` is heavily overloaded, that is, it dues many different things.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initalize your NiceBicycle object.

```
Bicycle NiceBicycle = new Bicycle( "Some value", 9972 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

`Bicycle NiceBicycle = new Bicycle("User2", 0);`

Then try to change the name of the owner

Answer (score 0):

You are having just a reference to a Bicycle object

```
Bicycle NiceBicycle;
```

Therefore actual Bicycle instance haven't created yet in the memory.
Before  you are setting the name you must create an actual instance first. Then try to set the name.

```
Bicycle NiceBicycle = new Bicycle(null, 0);
NiceBicycle.setOwnerName("Kenny McCormick");
```

Answer (score 0):

Andy you have created the constructor for Bicycle class that will set the name of Owner and licenseNumber. Ever time you create an object you use
 `new` 
keyword. As it performs some operations i-e 
`1` it will call the default constructor or overloaded constructor according to values you gave 
`2` it allocates the memory. That is why when you create an object of class you use 
`new` keyword
 now you are getting error because you have not properly initialized the object to initialize it you will do it as 
 `Bicycle NiceBicycle = new Bicycle("",0);`
 now to set values you will call its `Setter` and `Getter` methods like this
`NiceBicycle.setOwnerName("SetName")` 
now to get name you will call as 
`string OwnerName = NiceBicycle.getOwnerName()`